# iOS AVAudioSession, how to access AVAudioRecorder audio-level meter

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I am using a framework from a vendor, where the audio recording in the mobile app is initiated from `AVAudioSession` and can not find anywhere `AVAudioRecorder` in order to initiate the audio-level meter, to be displayed on the main screen.

Any hints or suggestions how to achieve this? How to get the current microphone level from `AVAudioSession`

Here is the code being used:

```
[AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {

    if (granted) {
        dispatch_async(self.audioSessionQueue, ^{
            NSError *error;
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:&error];
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];

            self.audioCaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
            [self.audioCaptureSession beginConfiguration];
AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
            AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioCaptureDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];

    if ([self.audioCaptureSession canAddInput:audioCaptureDeviceInput])
            {
                [self.audioCaptureSession addInput:audioCaptureDeviceInput];
            }
    else
            {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't add audio capture device input.");

                [self.audioCaptureSession commitConfiguration];
                return;
            }

            [self.audioCaptureReader setResultsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
            [self.audioCaptureSession addOutput:self.audioCaptureReader.captureOutput];

[self.audioCaptureSession commitConfiguration];
[self.audioCaptureSession startRunning];
}
```

Comment: I don't think `AVAudioSession` will give you an audio level meter, but you could add a `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` to your capture session and calculate the levels yourself.

Comment: Can you elaborate on AVCaptureAudioDataOutput?

Comment: It calls you back with audio samples from your audio `AVCaptureDevice`. You can use the samples to calculate levels.

Comment: any example of its usage? any website that i can see some more info on it how to implement it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This implements [@pesch's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5155181/pesch) excellent answer (you should accept it). I don't know if `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` is strictly necessary, but I don't know how else to get an `AVCaptureConnection`.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController () <AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *session;
@property (nonatomic) float averagePowerLevel;
@property (nonatomic) float volume;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:&error];
    // TODO: check audioInput != nil and error
    [self.session addInput:audioInput];

    AVCaptureAudioDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [self.session addOutput:output];

    [self.session startRunning];
}

// MARK: - AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    AVCaptureAudioChannel *channel = connection.audioChannels[0];


    self.averagePowerLevel = channel.averagePowerLevel;    // NB: not KVO-able!
    self.volume = channel.volume;    // KVO-able?

    NSLog(@"averagePowerLevel: %.2lf", self.averagePowerLevel);
}

@end
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't check the page lately, but thank you so much for the help. That is what i was looking. Just so you know channel.volume, for some reason doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Oh - I should update Xcode. It's still in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcaptureaudiochannel

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `volume` property in `AVCaptureAudioChannel`? Here's a link to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcaptureaudiochannel)

The volume property provides the current volume (gain) of the channel.